# Use Class From External Library As Model for MVC Controller Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to use the Code First database creation provided by EntityFramework. My hopes are to use this to create a website.

My issue comes when trying to create the controllers for the database context. I'm using a .dll to retrieve data from an API that I want to analyze and store in my own database. This dll has all the objects I may want in my db, so recreating these objects seems unnecessary. I want to treat these classes as my models instead of creating my own. However, I cannot point to the dll's classes when selecting the models in the **Add Controller** prompt.

Is it possible to do what I want? I have looked some for the answer to this question but my searches haven't been very fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the reference to your dll ?
Did you forgot "public" before your class ?

> public class Foo{..}

Comment: Yes, I have added the reference to my dll in the MVC project. Initially, I tried using the external library in my DbContext class like "public DbSet<ExternalClass> TableName { get; set; }" and went from there, but that did not solve my issue (the project did build, just could not add the controller using 'ExternalClass' as the Model).

Comment: Have you added the using reference on top of your DbContext class ?

Comment: Yes I had. I've found a minor workaround in creating models that inherit from the external classes, e.g. "public ModelClass : ExternalClass { }". This "works", although it's a bit sloppier than what I'd like. I'm getting new errors related to missing Ids but that's a different issue entirely.

Comment: "public DbSet<ExternalClass> TableName { get; set; }" does this line of code throw an error ?

Comment: @POB -  You also have to add the reference to any other assemblies that are using it as well, such as your MVC app.

Comment: No. I think you're kinda diagnosing the wrong problem. The entire project builds just fine. There are no errors at all. But when trying to create a new controller (Right-click "Controllers" -> Add -> Controller, select "MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework." This brings up the "Add Controller" prompt) my external classes are not accessible for the Model class dropdown.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch How do you mean? I have the project "MyMVCApp" which references a .dll which acts as an API wrapper and contains all of the objects I'd like. Is there more I need to do?

Comment: @POB - If your external class needs to be usable in your MVC app, then the external assembly has to be added to the MVC app, otherwise it won't know what the type is.  Unless your other dll wraps the external DLL and converts it to an entirely different type, this is necessary.